# ExtJs window doesn't show

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a toggle button:

```
        var button =  new Ext.Button({
        tooltip: "Интенсивность",
        iconCls: "gxp-icon-intensity",
        enableToggle:true,
        toggleHandler: function (button, state) {
            if(state){
                alert(state)
                map.getLayersByName("Интенсивность")[0].setVisibility(true);
                intWin.show();
            }else{
                map.getLayersByName("Интенсивность")[0].setVisibility(false);
                alert(intWin.collapsed);
                //intWin.close();
            }
        }
    });
```

And when the button is toggled I show a window:

```
    var intWin = new Ext.Window({
        id: 'intWin', 
        layout: 'fit',
        title:'Интенсивность',
        autoScroll:false,
        width:300,
        items:[/*intForm*/]
    });
```

When I close my window, then the button un-toggles. But when I click it again I don't get a window. Firebug shows this error:

```
 TypeError: b.dom is undefined

...String(this.enableUrlEncode)?this.enableUrlEncode:"data"]=Ext.encode(b);g.params...
```

What can be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Okey,my bad. I tried to show a destroyed element.

But in this case:
1 When I close the window and is destroyed, any forms in this window will be destroyed too?
2 How can I check that the window is destroyed?

**UPDATE2**

Now I try this function for creating the window:

```
    function intWinCreate(){
        var intWin = new Ext.Window({
            id: 'intWin', 
            layout: 'fit',
            title:'Интенсивность',
            autoScroll:false,
            width:300,
            items:[/*intForm*/]
        });
    };
```

and in the button handler:

```
                intWinCreate();
                intWin.show();
```

But I get an error:

```
  ReferenceError: intWin is not defined
```

If I put `intWin.show();` into the function then that window shows.
What can be wrong?

Comment: `intWin` is a local variable and is not accessible out of the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an element is destroyed everything within it also is destroyed.

In your case you change the default behaviour of close action to hide by setting the property `closeAction: 'hide'` it will cause the window to hide instead of getting destroyed.

Ex:

```
var intWin = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'intWin', 
    layout: 'fit',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    title:'Интенсивность',
    autoScroll:false,
    width:300,
    items:[/*intForm*/]
});
```

Update:
It is because `intWin` is a local variable in the method `intWinCreate`. What you can do is to return the window from the method and call show on it.

```
function intWinCreate(){
    return new Ext.Window({
        id: 'intWin', 
        layout: 'fit',
        title:'Интенсивность',
        autoScroll:false,
        width:300,
        items:[/*intForm*/]
    });
};
```

Then

```
intWinCreate().show()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, form usually is destroyed too
2. You can check, for example, intWin.body - if it is null - window is destroyed

**UPDATE**

As i see you have one answear already but I have another one for you too ;)
As long as you set

```
id: 'intWin'
```

You can access this window from anywhere using

```
Ext.getCmp()
```

so you can show it with this:

```
Ext.getCmp('intWin').show()
```